# What types of messaging middleware solutions are used by the biggest exchanges like Nasdaq, NYSE, ICE, NYMEX, Japan Exchange Group, Euronext, etc?

Tags: algorithmic-trading, exchange, trading-systems

Exchanges are famous for having to deal with a huge amount of messages. For example, some years (decades?) ago Nasdaq has migrated their reliable UDP protocol from 32-bit, which could support sequence numbers up to 4,294,967,295 to 64-bit, which can now support sequence numbers up to 18,446,744,073,709,551,615.

Some types of messaging middleware solutions are:

- [Atomic Broadcast](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atomic_broadcast)
- [Distributed Consensus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Consensus_(computer_science))
- External Ordered Queues

Which approach above and/or product (commercial/open source/in-house) are they using it? Is this information known to the tech community?